# How can i render the PMREM environment map when copying MeshStandardMaterial into a ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js

I am trying to build the `MeshStandardMaterial` by using a `ShaderMaterial`. I'm keeping most of the `#include <logic>` statements, which makes it slightly difficult to put breakpoints.

I'd like to know if there is a straightforward way to render the PMREM cubemap, in this particular material template and have it show up the way it's supposed to.

I'm roughly using:

```
material.defines.USE_ENVMAP = ''
material.defines.ENVMAP_MODE_REFLECTION = ''
material.defines.ENVMAP_TYPE_CUBE_UV = ''
material.defines.ENVMAP_BLENDING_MULTIPLY = ''
material.defines.TEXTURE_LOD_EXT = ''
material.defines.USE_UV = ''
material.extensions.derivatives = true
material.extensions.shaderTextureLOD = true
```

Which,as far as i can tell, are all of the defines that appear when adding a texture to `material.envmap`. The shader compiles, the PMREM texture is being generated, and can be read in the shader (`gl_FragColor = vec4( texture2D( envmap, vUv ).xyz, 1.)` works for example). These are the uniforms i cloned:

```
{
    envmap: UniformsUtils.clone(UniformsLib.envmap),
    fog: UniformsUtils.clone(UniformsLib.fog),
    lights: UniformsUtils.clone(UniformsLib.lights),
    displacementmap: UniformsUtils.clone(UniformsLib.displacementmap)
}
```

The `maxMipmap` uniform seems to have a value of 0 when `MeshStandardMaterial` is used, i'm not sure what else is being used.

I get absolutely no effect from placing a texture in `material.uniforms.envmap.value` and using these defines. If i turn off the light in the scene, my object renders as black, no reflections.

This doesn't seem like it requires that many inputs but i get 0. out of it:

```
    radiance += getLightProbeIndirectRadiance( /*specularLightProbe,*/ geometry.viewDir, geometry.normal, material.specularRoughness, maxMipLevel );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case it was a missing uniform:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js#L99

```
envMapIntensity: { value: 1 } // temporary
```

It's not part of the `envmap`.